# Designing a BMS for 2S2P 18650 batteries

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

I am trying to design a BMS for 4 18650 batteries in a 2S 2P configuration.

Some of the requirements are:

- I would like to charge and discharge from the same connectors
- I would like to implement a protection circuit to prevent over/under voltage and over/under charge
- I would like this system to be completely autonomous aka does not need a MCU

I have looked at numerous ICs and have found that I am struggling to understand how to connect these up to one another. For instance I have looked at the [MCP73842](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/21823D.pdf) and [S-8252](https://www.ablic.com/en/doc/datasheet/battery_protection/S8252_E.pdf) and tried to implement a circuit but I think the implementation is incorrect.

Could somebody look over the circuit and tell me if I am on the right track?
Could someone also explain how bms circuits are usually connected together?

Cheers
[image]

- To add, the provided system has one connection for charging (DC + and DC -) and another for discharging  (Eb+ and Eb-)

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, you say "Designing a BMS for 2S2P 18650 batteries".

On the other hand, you're using the [MCP73842](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/mcp73842), which is a  Charge Management Controller (not a BMS).

Given that you don't know the difference between charging and protecting, that implies that you may be a perfect candidate for using off-the-shelf solutions. (Especially given the serious consequence with playing with Li-ion without a sufficient understanding of the technology.)

1. Buy an off-the-shelf 2S Li-ion BMS, single port
2. Connect it as instructed to the Li-ion cells
3. Buy an off-the-shelf 2S Li-ion charger
4. Connect the charger to the BMS's port
5. Connect your load to the same BMS port
6. Done.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for commenting.

I appreciate your point but I am trying to learn how to design a system that can allow for charging and discharging from a single port whilst providing sufficient protection for the load.